# Как сделать выборку по количеству строк с одним и тем же значением

Tags: php, html, mysql

Имеется таблица, в ней хранятся внутренние id и внешние, строк с одним и тем же ID бывает несколько, обычно более 3-4, как сделать статистику из 20 строк, в которой будут выводиться внешние id содержащие как можно больше внутренних? 
Допустим

IDbig1 <
id1
id1
id1
id1
id1>

IDbig2 <
id2
id2
id2>

IDbig3 <
id3
id3>

Тоесть тут, в нескольких строках ID один, и соответствует внешнему, как отсортировать по убыванию и вывести в html таблицу это дело? Тоесть должно с этим примером получиться так - 
IDBIG1

IDBIG2

IDBIG3
.

При этом скрипт будет запускаться раз в 2 дня, тоесть обновлять статистику автоматически раз в 2 дня.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT extID, COUNT (intID)
FROM `table`
GROUP BY extID
ORDER BY 2 DESC
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло.

Answer (score 0):

Вам необходимо группировать результаты по повторяющимся id, для этого есть GROUP BY в итоге запрос будет примерно такой:

```
SELECT 'idbig' FROM 'table' GROUP BY 'id'
```

Comment: Это поможет, спасибо, а возможно ли как то вывести сначала наибольшее количество 'id' в группе первым, а затем уже и меньшее?